# What discussion alternatives have you used with SharePoint 2010...?

Tags: discussion-board

I'm just wondering what solutions people have implemented for discussion forums in SharePoint 2010.

Do you mostly opt to use the out-of-the-box discussion lists and web parts?

Are there alternative web parts that you have used?

Have you gone with a completely different solution for featuring discussions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find SharePoint's forums particularly poor. The guys at lightningtools [provide a third party solution](http://www.lightningtools.com/sharepoint-forum.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Muhimbi.  I had been looking at LightningTools.  I haven't been able to find many other good options besides them.